# Can't use data breakpoint C++, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, breakpoints

I set debugger to Native Only, solution configurations is Debug but New Data Breakpoint... option is still greyed out and I can't use it. Can anyone prompt me what else I need to change ?

Comment: One possibility is that the file you are referring to is not part of the source.  Close all files.  Pick the file from the solution and see if you can set a breakpoint.  Also is the section commented out?

Comment: I did this "One possibility is that the file you are referring to is not part of the source. Close all files. Pick the file from the solution and see if you can set a breakpoint" but without success. Section is probably not commented out, because i dont even know what you mean by " is the section commented out?". Would you be so kind to explain it to me ?

Comment: Is it inside an #if 0..#endif or /* */ comment block

Comment: No it is not. I want to track one variable of some class instance. What should I put into comment ?

Comment: Nothing - just that VS won't break in commented out code.  Is the code reachable?  VS won't let you set a breakpoint if the code is unreachable.  Alternatively, check your line endings - if you have a mix of CR & CRLF, that can cause problems.  Also, is the breakpoint in a DLL or in the exe?  If it is a DLL, you need the pdb for the DLL.

Comment: I am really sorry but I am a layman. I dont even know what "mix of CR & CRLF" means and  what is the difference between DLL and exe. I just have some .h nad .cpp files I thought taht it works similar to standard breakpoint but instead of marking line I would mark variable.

Comment: Ok i did it. I had to first run debugger and then add data breakpoint, not like with standard breakpoints.

Answer (score 27):

1. Make sure active project debugger setting is "Native Only".
2. Start the debugging with another ordinary breakpoint, then you can see "New Data Breakpoint" is clickable. (In other words, you must be inside debug mode to be able to create a data break point.)

Hope this helps..

Comment: +1.  I usually go back and forth between Native and Mixed mode setting; I never figured it could impact the Data breakpoint functionality.  Thank you *very* much!

Answer (score 6):

Also be sure to look at Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General and make sure "Enable address-level debugging" is checked.