# How to use data breakpoints in Visual Studio 2017, C++, CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, cmake, breakpoints

I've been using data breakpoints well in Visual Studio projects, but now I tried to switch to CMake ones. 
There, I cannot set them - data breakpoints are disabled all the time (grayed out).
Is it possible to use the instrument with CMake ? Similar problem with non-working data breakpoints (e.g. [Can't use data breakpoint C++, Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229878/cant-use-data-breakpoint-c-visual-studio-2013) ) was solved with Visual Studio project settings, which is not applicable in my case

Comment: You can make cmake generate VS solution and then adjust settings as required.

Comment: I guess the negative is regenerating will throw your changes to the settings out. Or doesn't it do that now? I have not touched the settings in VS for so long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Please add breakpoint firstly, and make sure that the breakpoint was hit before you add the data breakpoint.

(2) Please set the .exe as the startup item, view the result.

[image]

Comment: I always had .cpp as the startup item and (2) made the work. Thank you!